# Clear form data using php echo

Tags: javascript, php

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Success!');history.go(-1);</script>";
```

I'm using this to display Success and go back to form after submit the form. But I want to extend this code to clear input fields too. How should I do this? 
Thank You!

Comment: Modify the page that the form is on.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call

```
document.getElementById('formId').reset();
```